# openslide python import show:windows error

Tags: openslide

I am using python 2.7 win 32

I need to install openslide in python

in below page show 
Install openslide

http://openslide.org/download/

which item download for windows.

i tried every thing.and pip installation

the error shows below

> import openslide

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import openslide
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openslide\__init__.py", line 29, in >>>>  <module>
    from openslide import lowlevel
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openslide\lowlevel.py", line 41, in <module>
    _lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libopenslide-0.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This question may be old, but perhaps an answer will help a future viewer.

To fix this error, you need to download the openslide binaries at http://openslide.org/download/ look under (Windows Binaries)

Next, add the location of the bin folder to your system path (this will allow python to know where the module is). And that should solve the problem.

Install instructions found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openslide-python